# copy data to cells based on date

Tags: vba, excel

so i have 2 workbooks, helper.xlsm and weekly data.xlsx 
what i would like to do is copy data from cells D3 G3 P3 R3 and T3 from helper.xlsm sheet 11
to the same column on weekly data.xlsx sheet 1 but different cells based on date in column B in both workbooks

so data from this book
[image: helper book]

to this book based on date in column B
[image: weekly data book]

i need to match the to dates then copy and paste 
for example if date = 19-september the data needs to be pasted into row 309
20th would be 310 ect any help would be great and if you could take the time to explain the code as well that would be fantastic as i trying to learn vba

Comment: What is `.Range("")`?

Comment: that would be `.Range("D309")` for example it needs to change for each day so tomorrow would be `.Range("D310")`

Comment: It would be helpful if you can provide screen prints of your worksheets and a screen print of what you are trying to achieve because its not clear from your question what it is you are trying to achieve. Also, do you have to use VBA for this? If I understand your question (which I'm not convinced that I do), you might be able to do this with just formulas

Comment: i believe formulas are no good due to it being in different workbooks not different sheets i cant use vba i the destination book as its head office that wrote it and wont let me change it.

Comment: Apart from the Range(""), what is your problem when running the code?

Comment: i dont know vba at all but i belive the code im looking for is a for loop so the the blank `.Range("")` will be D309 if today 19-september then tomorrow will D310 if the date is 20-september ect. the code to copy the data from one sheet to the other works fine i just dont wont to write 352 if elseif statments.

Comment: im googleing all this awell looking at for and even .find but im just not understanding it all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your are looking for a macro that will copy certain data from a current file to a destination spreadsheet, you may try the below code.

It opens a browse window for the destination file, like this:

File open dialog - destination file:

[image]

Here's the code:

```
Sub exportday()
    Dim fileStr As String, srcBk As Workbook, destBk As Workbook, rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range, tmpDt As Date
    Set srcBk = ThisWorkbook
    ChDrive srcBk.Path
    ChDir srcBk.Path

'    get destination file
    fileStr = Application.GetOpenFilename("Destination file (*.xls*),*.xls*")
    If fileStr = "False" Then Exit Sub
    Set destBk = Workbooks.Open(fileStr)
    Sheets("day sales").Select

'    get source row
    For Each rng1 In srcBk.Sheets(1).Columns("B").Cells
        If rng1 > 0 Then
            tmpDt = rng1
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

'    get destination row and update values
    For Each rng2 In destBk.Sheets("day sales").Columns("B").Cells
        If rng2 = tmpDt Then
            rng2.Offset(0, 2) = rng1.Offset(0, 2)   'col D
            rng2.Offset(0, 5) = rng1.Offset(0, 5)   'col G
            rng2.Offset(0, 14) = rng1.Offset(0, 14) 'col P
            rng2.Offset(0, 16) = rng1.Offset(0, 16) 'col R
            rng2.Offset(0, 18) = rng1.Offset(0, 18) 'col T
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    destBk.Close savechanges:=True
    MsgBox "Spreadsheet " & fileStr & " updated.", vbInformation, "Success"
End Sub
```

Assumption:

- Source spreadsheet (where the macro resides) has only 1 sheet

Comment: thank you for this the source book is the book the macro runs from so trying to reopen would fail?

Comment: ok then try now? i hv updated the answer as per your request. n btw u dont need to remove your codes. it shows what u tried

Comment: thank howerver i get run time error 91 doing debug shows `rng2.Offset(0, 2) = rng1.Offset(0, 2)   'col D` i also edit my question before i saw you post :)

Comment: hard to tell as i am not getting any error. what if u add `.value`? like `rng2.Offset(0, 2).Value = rng1.Offset(0, 2).Value   'col D`

Comment: still error 91 object var or with block var not set. ill keep playing about at least im getting a slightly better understanding of how it works now so thank you

Comment: `rng1.offset(0, 2)` is whats causing runtime error 91

Comment: all sorted thank you very very much it was a problem in `srcbook.sheets.(1)` i forgot that its not the only sheet in that workbook. you are a life saver thank you very much